# AngularJS angular.js:12520 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL affiliate window

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When including the below code into my single page AngularJS app I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

The code is placed inside one of my view files and is populated from an AngularJS controller.

When I remove the JavaScript part and just insert the img tag it works perfectly as expected. Any ideas why this error is happening and how to fix it?

```
<!-- Javascript Tracking - Mandatory --> 
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[ 

/*** Do not change ***/
var AWIN = {};
AWIN.Tracking = {};
AWIN.Tracking.Sale = {};

/*** Set your transaction parameters ***/
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.amount = ‘{{order_subtotal}}’;
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.orderRef = ‘{(order_ref}}’;
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.parts = ‘DEFAULT:{{sale_amount}}’;
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.voucher = ‘{{voucher_code}}’;
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.currency = ‘GBP’;
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.test = ‘0’;
AWIN.Tracking.Sale.channel = ‘aw’;
//]]>
</script>


<!--Master Tag add just before the closing </body> tag-->
<script src="https://www.dwin1.com/{{merchant_ID}}.js" type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script>
```

Comment: You have a typo on order_ref line. Should be {{ but you have {(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your single quote is wrong, should be ' not ’